# Sticky sidebar is jolty if its shorter than the window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sticky sidebar that when you scroll becomes fixed when the bottom of the sidebar is in view.

If the sidebar exceeds the length of the page as it does in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9bmpkp8/) all works fine when you scroll and is exactly what you would expect.

However if the sidebar is shorter than the window height as in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9bmpkp8/4/), it seems to be jumping when you scroll and I can't work out how to get it to stop jumping and to be smooth. In other words it should only be fixed when the base of the sidebar hits the base of the window.

I'm not great with jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function () {  
  if ($('.leftsidebar').offset()!=null) {

    var top = $('.leftsidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('.leftsidebar').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var height = $('.leftsidebar').height();
    var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#footer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var gap = 7;

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {

      // what the y position of the scroll is
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();

      // whether that's below the form
      if (y+winHeight >= top+ height+gap && y+winHeight<=footerTop) {

          // if so, ad the fixed class
          $('.leftsidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', winHeight-height-gap +'px');
      } 

      else if (y+winHeight>footerTop) {
          // if so, ad the fixed class
          $('.leftsidebar').addClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', footerTop-height-y-gap + 'px');
      } 
      else {
          // otherwise remove it
           $('.leftsidebar').removeClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', '0px');
      }
    });
  }  
});
```

Is it possible to combine the two instances? So if its shorter stay relative till the sidebar reaches the bottom, then act as it is now if the sidebar is longer?

Answer (score 0):

The code works just as intended. This is actually a conceptual problem.

Picture how it would work first. The way you described it working seems to be exactly how it's working in your demo. When the sidebar is longer than the page, the scrolling page reaches the bottom of the sidebar before the leftsidebarfixed is added. That would be impossible with a shorter sidebar.

You may want to consider fixing the sidebar to the top, instead of the bottom (as most websites with sticky sidebars do) or having a taller header, so that the sidebar starts at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code I am using was taken from a tutorial, so basically you're saying that this code only works when the sidebar is longer than the page. Am I able to adapt in order to achieve both instances or would I need to start from scratch?